# Displaying a particular section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been searching around but cant seem to find the answer to this particular problem that I have been facing. This is a general chat app that I'm experimenting on and my aim is to only display a certain section given if it's a single convo or a group convo.  As you can see on the code below

```
#define bGroupNameSection 0
#define bParticipantsSection 1
#define bAddParticipantSection 2
#define bLeaveConvoSection 3
#define bSectionCount 4
```

So what it is doing currently is displaying the first section which is  bGroupNameSection in both a private conversation or a group chat. However i want only the participant section to show if it is a private conversation.

Here are some screenshots to aid in understanding what i mean.

[image: Group chat]

[image: Single Chat]

[image: How it should be on a single chat]

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//to check if its a group or single chat and to return the amount of sections.
return _thread.type.intValue == bThreadTypePrivateGroup ? bSectionCount : 1;
}
```

Am i able to do any form of conditional checking here whereby

```
if(it is a private chat) { 
    // make bParticipantsSection 0
       bAddParticipantSection 1
       bLeaveConvoSection 2
       bSectionCount 3

       remove bGroupNameSection
}
```

Here is any other relevant code that might help.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (section == bParticipantsSection) {
    return _users.count ? _users.count : 1;
}
if (section == bLeaveConvoSection || section == bAddParticipantSection || section ==  bGroupNameSection) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:bCell];

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if (indexPath.section == bParticipantsSection) {

        if (_users.count) {

            CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

            id<PUser> user = _users[indexPath.row];

            cell.textLabel.text = user.name;
            cell.imageView.image = user && user.thumbnail ? [UIImage imageWithData:user.thumbnail] : [NSBundle chatUIImageNamed: @"icn_user.png"];

            cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
            cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

            itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
            CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
            [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
            cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSBundle t:bNoActiveParticipants];
            cell.imageView.image = nil;
        }

        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = _users.count ? NSTextAlignmentLeft : NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.selectionStyle = _users.count ? UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault :UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == bAddParticipantSection) {

        // Reset the image view
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSBundle t:bAddParticipant];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == bLeaveConvoSection) {

        // Reset the image view
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSBundle t:bLeaveConversation];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == bGroupNameSection) {
        UITextField *groupNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 30)];
        groupNameTextField.delegate = self;
        groupNameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        groupNameTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        groupNameTextField.text = _thread.displayName;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:groupNameTextField];
    }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your specific problem is? It's not clear whether those screenshots are the desired or incorrect functionality, and even then there is no context to discern what is actually going on in them.

Comment: Hello @stonz2 sorry for not labeling my screenshots so the first screenshot shows the details of the group chat and how the sections of them , second is how a private conversation details looks like and 3rd is how  a private conversation should look like. i would want the participant section to show rather than the "group name" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined the group section to be 0 so even when you're in a private chat your code will think its group (giving it the wrong header and cell).

I'd suggest moving your section numbers from *#defines* into instance variables that you initialise. e.g In your private interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger groupNameSection;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger participantSection;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger addParticipantSection;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger leaveConvoSection;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger sectionCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isPrivateChat;
```

Then:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSInteger sectionCount = 0;
    self.groupNameSection = self.isPrivateChat ? sectionCount++ : -1; // If private chat, groupName section -1, otherwise its 0 (and sectionCount is incremented for next)
    self.participantSection = sectionCount++;
    self.addParticipantSection = sectionCount++;
    self.leaveConvoSection = sectionCount++;
    self.sectionCount = sectionCount;
}
```

In your relevant cellForRow and headerForRow methods you can then compare the section number to the properly initialised instance variables. e.g.

```
if (indexPath.section == self.addParticipantSection) {
    // Handle section data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are predefining the values as constants, and comparing it with the indexpath.section, which will vary based on the type of chat.

You should create a array to keep the array of sections to be displayed, based on the type of chat(Single or Group). Declare array of sections:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray * sectionArray;
```

Initialise the section array,

```
//For Single Chat

       self.sectionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:bParticipantsSection], nil];


//For Group
       self.sectionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:bGroupNameSection],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:bParticipantsSection],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:bAddParticipantSection],
                                 nil];
```

Now, in number of sections, return sectionArray count

In number of rows ins section,

```
if ([self.sectionArray objectAtIndex: section] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:bGroupNameSection])
    {
         return 1;
    }
 else if ([self.sectionArray objectAtIndex: section] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:bAddParticipantSection])
    {
        return 1;
    }
 else
   {
        //...
   }
```

In cellForRow,

```
if ([self.sectionArray objectAtIndex: indexpath.section] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:bGroupNameSection])
{
    //return group name cell
}
 else 
{
   //...
}
```